# How to temporarily suppress output from printf?

Tags: c++, linux

In a console application I am calling a library function that outputs some messages (probably using printf) that I am not interested in:

```
void libFoo()
{
    // does some stuff
    printf("boring message");
    // does some more stuff
}
```

I tried suppressing cout before which didn't work, hence why I think libFoo is using printf:

```
cout << "interesting messsage" << endl;
streambuf* orig_buf = cout.rdbuf();
cout.rdbuf(NULL);
libFoo();
cout.rdbuf(orig_buf);
cout << "another interesting messsage" << endl;
```

This code outputs all these messages.  Is there a way to temporarily suppress output from printf?  I am using Linux Mint.

Comment: you could overwrite printf lib call.

Comment: You can, but I don't think you can do it completely portably. Look at freopen and dup functions.

Comment: Keep in mind that cout is buffered, while cerr isn't. If you disable something make sure that the buffer is flushed.

Comment: Maybe your lib is using a logging feature, and not specifically `printf`... If this possibility exists, consider figuring out how to set the log level...

Comment: "boring message" might me displayed on `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Comment: In my case I was able to set the logging level to 0 on the library, but the question still stands for those that don't have the option of doing this.

Comment: I think the only defined way to do it would be to redirect `stdout` to somewhere else, like `/dev/null`, and then restore it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
int supress_stdout() {
  fflush(stdout);

  int ret = dup(1);
  int nullfd = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
  // check nullfd for error omitted
  dup2(nullfd, 1);
  close(nullfd);

  return ret;
}

void resume_stdout(int fd) {
  fflush(stdout);
  dup2(fd, 1);
  close(fd);
}
```

If this is C++, also flush `cout` for good measure.

**EDITED TO CLARIFY**

The `fd` you pass to `resume_stdout` is the same one you received as `supress_stdout`'s return value.

Comment: What do you pass for the parameter fd?

Comment: @tyebillion, The int you got from `suspend_stdout`

Comment: Yeah, that worked for me.  I just had to #include <fcntl.h> to get the definition of O_WRONLY.